# Slicing tensor with int32 shape with int64 scalar

Tags: python, indexing, tensorflow

Consider the following code:

```
x = tf.Variable([1.0,2.0,3.0])
i = tf.Variable([1], dtype = tf.int64)
x[i]
```

tensorflow throws error, apparently, because type of shape of x is different from type of i. I can solve it by casting i to int32, but is there some other way? For example can I change the type of shape of x?

Comment: "can I change the type of shape of x?" ... that's what you do by casting `i` to `int32`. `x[tf.cast(i, tf.int32)]` should do what you want without modifying `i` (although you will have truncation on the values in `i` if they are too big for an `int32`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, tensorflow does not support the slicing via `__getitem__` as numpy does. The alternative is to use `tf.gather`:

```
x = tf.Variable([1.0,2.0,3.0])
i = tf.Variable([1], dtype = tf.int64) 
tf.gather(x, i)
```